# python + selenium button in div overlay clickable in testing but not when automated

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

```
<div class="t-window-content t-content" style="overflow: auto; width: 400px; height: 389.4px;">
    <div id="frmSchTarget">
        <form action="/Search/SearchTypePreName"
            method="post" onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event));"
            onsubmit="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleSubmit(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, onBegin: Function.createDelegate(this, PreNameListWindow), onSuccess: Function.createDelegate(this, Form_OnSuccess) });"><input type="hidden" id="NameList"
                name="NameList">
            <div style="text-align: left; padding-left: 10px">
                <span style="margin-right: 20px;">
        <button id="TreeViewButtonCollapse" name="TreeViewButtonCollapse" onclick="ExpandCollapseTreeView('NameListTreeView', false); return false;" title="Collapse All">
            <img src="/Content/Images/toggle_up.png">
        </button>
        <button id="TreeViewButtonExpand" name="TreeViewButtonExpand" onclick="ExpandCollapseTreeView('NameListTreeView', true); return false;" title="Expand All">
            <img src="/Content/Images/toggle_down.png">
        </button>
    </span>
            </div>
            <div id="divSelectNamesArea" style="height: 325px; overflow: auto;">
                "i removed a very large list from here"
            </div>
            <hr class="PopupLineStyle">
            <div style="text-align: left; padding-left: 10px">
                <span style="margin-right: 20px;"><input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1" name="SelectAllPrenamesToggle" onclick="SelectAllOrNoneInTreeView('NameListTreeView', this.checked);">
    All / None</span>
                <input type="submit" class="t-button" value="Done"
                    onclick="GetNameListString('NameListTreeView');">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code has basically been the bane of my existence for about a week now. I am trying to run a webscraper and upon submitting a request a div overlay appears on the page. The code snippet above shows how the 'Done' button used to get rid of it is implemented.

In testing I am able to use

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[contains(@class,"t-button")]')
```

to find all buttons present and then it is button [5], however once I automate this does not work.

I have also tried an implicit wait with the following xpath:

```
//*[@id="frmSchTarget"]/form/div[3]/input
```

This also is a no-go. Please help, I have been trying just about everything an searched through stackoverflow for over a week already. I just can't figure it out.

Comment: There's nothing that pops out at me that would require an implicit wait. could you provide the URL?

Comment: Try a more specific selector. A useful feature is Chrome's CSS selector generator. In the Chrome Inspector, right click on the element you want >> Copy >> Copy Selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// wait 15s before click button for debug purpose, in case click button before 
// it be rendered out on page

```
time.sleep(15)

button_done = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#frmSchTarget input[value='Done']")

button_done.click()
```

if above code work, remove the time.sleep() and run again, if failed,  it means 
you need wait some moment before click it, please use explicit wait replace time.sleep()

Comment: [edit] Sorry, forgot to put, the click() method. This works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: please replace the sleep() to explicit wait in official script

Comment: `<div class="t-widget t-window" id="NamesWin"
    style="visibility: visible; top: 240px; left: 305px; z-index: 10029; display: block;">
    <div class="t-window-titlebar t-header">&nbsp;<span class="t-window-title">Select Names:</span>
        <div
            class="t-window-actions t-header"><a class="t-link" href=""><span class="t-icon t-close">Close</span></a></div>
</div>
<div class="t-window-content t-content" style="overflow: auto; width: 400px; height: 385.4px;">
    <div id="frmSchTarget">No names found. Try
        again.</div>
</div>
</div>` how close button?

Comment: button_close = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#NamesWin .t-close")